# Animation flickers on Android device

Tags: android, animation, codenameone

Following up on my previous post on animation trouble ([Codename One Animation Trouble (also in Solitaire demo)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743873/codename-one-animation-trouble-also-in-solitaire-demo)) in my app and in the Solitaire demo. The simulator and iOS problems are solved, but there remains the issue on Android devices. (Test: Nexus 7, Android 5.1.1; CN1 3.3.1)

In my checkers app, when the computer makes a move, the checker starts moving but the destination square briefly flashes (while the undo/redo animations work fine). This is similar to what happens in Solitaire: when a card starts auto-moving, but only if it is the second move or higher in a row, the card it will land on top of usually flashes (as if the button is pressed?). This also happens in the deal-from-deck animation (many moves in a row).

In my app it looks like the checker is very briefly (one frame?) shown at the destination location and then it starts moving from the source location to the destination location as it should. The same probably applies to Solitaire.

In issue #1640 you mentioned: 
'This is probably related to the Android pipeline work we are doing and has nothing to do with the animation framework. We'll take a look at that and try to figure out what happened there.'

When is the improved Android pipeline scheduled?
Would you like me to submit a new issue for this?

Comment: It may be helpful if you linked your previous post ;)

Comment: Link to previous post added.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works better with issues ideally with smaller scopes (one issue per post) and ideally with a simple test case the demonstrates the issue.

The [issue tracker](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/) is probably a better place for bugs than stack overflow.

Comment: I filed a new issue, #1654.